parametrization for $y^{2} = x(x-1)(x-2)$
I need to find the tangent line of the curve:
$$C = \{ (x,y) : y^{2} = x(x-1)(x-2) \}$$
at point $p = (0,0)$, so I want to find $g:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ s.t $\text{Im}(g) = C$ and then find the linear approximation at the point $(0,0)$, but I can't find how to define such $g$, in a previous exercise we had $y^{2}=x^{3}$ and here the function is pretty easy ($g(t) = (t^{2},t^{3})$) because $y = x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ and $x \geq 0$ then we get this $g$, but in my case I can't see how we can define such $g$ so easily.
I've seen in this site some general formula (which involves pretty hard computations that we need some code to do the procedure), but I'm thinking that it can be solved with more elementary way.
Thank you all in advance!

Have you plotted the curve ?

@JeanMarie
Of course, and I know that it's x=0 but I need to show that formally and for that I have to find a parametrization.

This is an elliptic curve, so it doesn't have a rational parametrization.

Use implicit differentiation. So here we assume $y$ is a function of $x$ and take derivatives with respect to $x$ on both sides. Using the chain rule on $y$ we have $2y\frac{dy}{dx} = 3x^{2} - 6x + 3$ and solving we have $$\frac{dy}{dx} = \frac{3x^{2} - 6x + 3}{2y}$$ so the slope will be infinite at $(0,0)$ or, alternatively you can say $\frac{dx}{dy}=0$ so the line is vertical.

Are you sure? The derivative of the RHS seems to be $3x^{2} - 6x + 3$.

@M.Wind thanks! I did the example from his class, not the problem he was working on.

I'm sorry for the delayed comment, but I'll be glad if you can explain me how can we think of $y$ as a function of $x$? I'm not sure we can use the implicit function theorem but even if we can it doesn't implies that we can write $y=y(x)$ near $(0,0)$, we can write $x=x(y)$ but there is another justification for that assumption without using the implicit function theorem?

@oneneedsanswers the function $y \to y^2$ is invertible at $0$ so we can treat $y$ as a function of $x$ near $0$. However if you prefer to argue that $x$ is a function of $y$ you'll find that you get the same answer. It might be instructive for you to do it that way as a double check.

You don't need to actually find a parametrization here, all you need is that there exists one locally around $p$. This one can use something like the implicit function theorem to guarantee. So suppose we have such a local parametrization, say $(x,y):(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)\to\mathbb R^2$ for some small $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x(t),y(t))\in C$ for all $t\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ and $(x(0),y(0))=p=(0,0)$. Then we can differentiate both sides of the equation
$$y(t)^2=x(t)(x(t)-1)(x(t)-2)=x(t)^3-3x(t)^2+2x(t)$$
to get that
$$2y'(t)y(t)=3x'(t)x(t)^2-6x'(t)x(t)+2x'(t).$$
Since we're interested in the tangent at $p$, and our parametrization hits $p$ when $t=0$, we can plug in $t=0$ (and use that $x(0)=y(0)=0$) to get that $x'(0)=0$. This defines the tangent line, so the tangent line as a subset of $\mathbb R^2$ is then set
$$\{(a,b)\in\mathbb R^2: (a,b)=p+(x'(0),y'(0))t\text{ for some }t\in\mathbb{R}\}=\{(0,t)\in\mathbb R^2:t\in\mathbb R^2\},$$
i.e. it is the $y$-axis.
